# Acumatica BQL with multiple joins

Tags: sql, acumatica

I have a custom table that stores a reference to the `Users.PKID` Guid & need to execute the following simple SQL query through the Acumatica framework (*BQL*).

```
SELECT 
    -- *
    L.LeaveTransactionId,
    L.EmployeeId,
    E.Name AS EmployeeName,
    E.ManagerId,
    M.Name AS ManagerName,
    M.UserId AS ManagerUserId
FROM LeaveTransaction AS L

INNER JOIN Employee AS E
    ON L.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId

INNER JOIN Employee AS M
    ON E.ManagerId = M.EmployeeId

WHERE M.UserId = '...'
```

I have a single join as follows but cannot see any method to specify multiple joins.

```
public PXProcessingJoin<LeaveTransaction,
            InnerJoin<DAC.Employee, On<DAC.Employee.employeeId, Equal<DAC.LeaveTransaction.employeeId>>>> LeaveTransactions;
```

Is there any way to expand the *BQL* to join 2 **or more** tables?

*Please note that the data should be merged and not read-only as the dataset is also filtered on a `Selected` bool allowing users to select 1 or more items in the grid view.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload for all implementations of the `BaseJoin` type with a 'NextJoin' generic parameter e.g. `InnerJoin<Table, On, NextJoin>`.

The sql example above is represented with:

```
public PXProcessingJoin<LeaveTransaction,
            InnerJoin<DAC.Employee, On<DAC.Employee.employeeId, Equal<DAC.LeaveTransaction.employeeId>>,
            InnerJoin<DAC.Manager, On<Manager.employeeId, Equal<DAC.Employee.managerId>>>>,
            Where<LeaveTransaction.status, Equal<LeaveStatus.submitted>,
                And<Manager.userId, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>> LeaveTransactions;
```

Because this example contains a circular Foreign Key, an additional Data Access Class (*DAC*) derived from the standard definition is needed inorder to generate the correct SQL query. In this scenario the `Manager` class is defined as a derived type from `Employee`, any fields queried in BQL specific to this class must be overridden (otherwise the generated SQL will reference the base type).

```
[Serializable]
public class Manager : Employee
{
    public new abstract class employeeId : IBqlField {}
    public new abstract class userId : PX.Data.IBqlField {}
}
```